# How to Check which HTML Select from Multiple Selects changed without JS

Tags: php, html

Not sure why in practice this would not work, but i am trying to make a page reload after submit, but with multiple `<select>`'s.

Each has it's own name, but how do I know which was changed on `$_POST`, without giving each select its own form.

Here is the current code:

```
<form id="productSelectedForm" action="products.php?filter=true" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="model" value="<?php echo $item['model']; ?>" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label><strong>Select available Grade: </strong>
        <select id="gradeSelect" class="propChanged" name="grade" onchange="this.form.submit();">
          <?php foreach( $props[ 'grade'] as $g) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>">
            <?php echo $g; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><strong>Select available Colour:</strong>
        <select id="colourSelect" class="propChanged" name="colour" onchange="this.form.submit();">
          <?php foreach( $props[ 'colour'] as $g) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>">
            <?php echo $g; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><strong>Select available Storage:</strong>
        <select id="storageSelect" class="propChanged" name="storage" onchange="this.form.submit();">
          <?php foreach( $props[ 'storage'] as $g) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>">
            <?php echo $g; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label><strong>Select available Network:</strong>
        <select id="networkSelect" class="propChanged" name="network" onchange="this.form.submit();">
          <?php foreach( $props[ 'network'] as $g) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>">
            <?php echo $g; ?>
          </option>
          <?php } ?>
        </select>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Is there any way to do this without using Javascript and individual forms, that i am missing ?

Thanks

Addy

Comment: Why can't you use Javascript? It would be the best solution. With Ajax you can only post the input that triggered the submit function instead of all the values.

Comment: Why do you need to know which one was changed?

Comment: @Brainfeeder I could use Javascript, but I do need the page to refresh as a number of elements would change based on the selection made.  So it would be easier to just know which changed.

Comment: @MoshFeu At the moment, when it POSTs it brings all values back, but the combination may not fit in the next function. So I just want to change the one which was changed, and then replace the other select boxes with what is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given PHP it can be seen that you do not pre-select a certain option for the `SELECT` elements, so the browser will select the first by default.

Then when the user submits the form you cannot make the distinction between a voluntary, conscious  choice for that first item, or whether the user just changed another `SELECT` and did not do anything with this one.

I would suggest to start every `SELECT` with a first option that is empty, and has an empty `VALUE` attribute, like this:

```php
      <option value=""><option>
      <?php foreach( $props[ 'grade'] as $g) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>">
        <?php echo $g; ?>
      </option>
      <?php } ?>
```

Then when you process the `$_POST` data, you will know whether the user made an explicit choice if the value is not empty, for example:

```
if (!empty($_POST['grade'])) {
    // a grade was specified by the user.
}
```

#### Keeping State

Although your code does not seem to keep track of previously made selections, you might probably want that, and so you should somehow store those previous selections. Once you are able to do that, you will be able to find out what changed by comparing the previous values with the current submitted values.

You could use session variables for keeping track of the user's choices:

```
session_start();

// detect change and remember current selections
$changed = array();
foreach (array("grade", "colour", "storage", "network") as $key) {
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
        if (empty($_SESSION[$key]) || $_POST[$key] != $_SESSION[$key]) {
            $changed[] = $key;
        }
        $_SESSION[$key] = $_POST[$key];
    } else {
        $_SESSION[$key] = "";
    }
}
```

After this code has run you will have in the array *$changed* the list of items (e.g. *["storage"]* ) that have a changed value. Normally, it should not be possible that more than one value changes at a time (since you submit immediately on a change), but who knows...

Then in your form you should make sure the user keeps the previously selected items selected, for example, for grade:

```
    <select id="gradeSelect" class="propChanged" name="grade" onchange="this.form.submit();">
      <?php foreach( $props[ 'grade'] as $g) { ?>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="<?php echo $g; ?>"
            <?php if ($g == $_SESSION["grade"]) echo " selected "; ?>
        >
        <?php echo $g; ?>
      </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Yes, but this would not fit a case where this form is a settings page where previously saved data is loaded on page load :)

Comment: True, but that was not mentioned in the question. If OP does such a thing, I invite those details to be added to the question.

Comment: You have a point there. The field names suggest a product search filter.

Comment: It is a product search filter, but it is filtering based on available stock.  So if a user clicks a Network, it should bring all products with that model and network, and the rest of the properties of the highest price.  In this case, it could mean the Colour Gold is populated, as that would give a higher price, than a Silver.  But it should only show based on available stock.  At the moment i have put it so there is a form on each select.  And like Trincot, use Session Storage to record the filter changes per product.   I just thought on paper there would be another way.

Comment: There is: (1) a form per select (no harm in that, and user does not notice the difference); (2) use JavaScript: (2)(a) ... to fill in a hidden input that identifies the select that has been changed; (2)(b) ... to load the complete hierarchy of items based on available stock in memory and let user work on client side, until final selection is made (nice user experience). (2)(c) make Ajax calls to retrieve the lists based on the last made selection and update the selects. ...etc.

Comment: @trincot  Thank you. I have marked your answer with a tick.  As it does answer how to achieve it.  Thank you for your time.